# Python CSV Robinhood

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am trying to run the code from this link on a Windows 10 system using Python 3.6: https://github.com/joshfraser/robinhood-to-csv but I keep runnning into the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv-export.py", line 46, in <module>
    logged_in = robinhood.login(username=username, password=password)
  File "C:\Users\rebel\Desktop\Robinhood\robinhood-to-csv-master\Robinhood.py", line 81, in login
    res = res.json()
  File "C:\Users\rebel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rebel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\rebel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\rebel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I am really not sure what could be wrong here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I created a python script which exports robinhood stock and options data to excel. Here you go:

https://github.com/arungeorge101/myRobinhoodData

Answer (score 1):

`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` indicates that the server returns an empty response since the JSON decoder expects a value at the first character but is not getting any. Something likely went wrong on the server side so it is not returning any content. You should use a debugger to check the [`status_code`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) of the response object `res` to understand the nature of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will fetch your Robinhood holds and write them to a CSV file.

Import some python packages first:

```
pip install pandas
pip install robin-stocks
```

And here is the code:

```
import config
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import robin_stocks as r

username = 'john@example.com'
password = 'PASSWORD'

today = datetime.date.today()

ordered_columns = [
    'name',
    'quantity',
    'price',
    'average_buy_price',
    'percent_change',
    'equity',
    'type',
    'percentage'
]

login = r.login(config.robinhood_username, config.robinhood_password)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(r.build_holdings())
transpose = df.T
transpose = transpose.drop(['id', 'equity_change', 'pe_ratio'], axis=1)
transpose = transpose.sort_index()
transpose.to_csv(f'robinhood-{today}.csv', header=True, columns=ordered_columns, index=True)
```